# breaking long line in HTML source without line breaks appearing on page

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of code that looks like this:

```
        <textarea class="normalPara" rows="auto" cols="80" wrap="hard" disabled>
abcdefg Ojisslk myfadeww klkkso mnbuyt ioA[Q opllisddfl kemcjdosidns   okk aswooerkccls jjepo zevert plice jkeuiic heynmbb llloe
        </textarea>
```

For purposes of readability and neatness, I would like to indent the long string and have it appear in the source like this:

```
        <textarea class="normalPara" rows="auto" cols="80" wrap="hard" disabled>
            abcdefg Ojisslk myfadeww klkkso mnbuyt ioA[Q opllisddfl kemcjdosidns
            okk aswooerkccls jjepo zevert plice jkeuiic heynmbb llloe
        </textarea>
```

The problem is that wherever I put a CR or indent the line in the source, the line break / indent is faithfully reproduced in the page, so the wrapping in a textarea that is narrower than my source lines looks wonky.

I know there is a way to do this, and I suspect I'll feel dumb when someone points me at it, I just can't find the technique after searching for it, I think I'm just not searching with the right terms...

Comment: I think you might be a bit pedantic. Who cares what the source looks like, as long as it looks correct on the UI, who cares what it looks like in the source? Or are your users going to be forced to view the source?

Comment: No one but me or associates should ever see the source, the beatification is just intended to ease maintenance.

Comment: I'm currently working with a DBA that has the same attitude. The users never sees the database backend, but he designs it for "ease of maintenance" so that you can "easily see" the data. Which in turns has had such a huge affect on performance, that we're now forced to upgrade hardware because he is too pig headed to change the database. There's better ways to spend your time :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution 3036342 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how textarea works. What you type is exactly what you get. Sadly, that isn't the place to be readable. You'll have to live with having your code slightly uglier there.

Like `<pre>`, all line breaks and spaces are preserved.

---

Also, you shouldn't care about how your *end source* looks like, in fact, you *end source*, the one presented to the client should be gzipped and minified to conserve bandwidth as much as possible.

What you *should* be concerned is your *development source*. The source that you actually develop continuously.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking.  I just started using <div>s instead of textareas and that does just what I need.  Thanks for the pointers and info.